# Shapeless: foldLeft on hlist compilation error

Tags: scala, types, shapeless

Can not get foldLeft working on HList when folding to List, when i fold Hlist to a string everything works fine.

```
object wrapInList extends Poly1 {
  implicit def intCase = at[Int]{v => List(v)}
  implicit def stringCase = at[String]{v => List(v)}
}

object mergeToString extends Poly1 {
  implicit def intCase = at[Int](_.toString())
  implicit def stringCase = at[String](identity)
}

object foldListPoly extends Poly2 {
  implicit  def foldToList[T](implicit st: wrapInList.Case.Aux[T, List[T]]) =
    at[List[T], T]{ (acc, t) => acc ::: wrapInList(t) }
  implicit def foldToString[T](implicit st: mergeToString.Case.Aux[T, String]) =
    at[String, T]{ (acc, t) => acc + mergeToString(t)}
}

val hList = "aoeu" :: 42 :: HNil
val foldedHlist = hList.foldLeft("")(foldListPoly)
val foldedHList2 = hList.foldLeft(Nil)(foldListPoly)
```

---

Erorr on compiling foldedHList2

```
could not find implicit value for parameter folder:
shapeless.ops.hlist.LeftFolder[shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil]],scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type,com.test.Test.foldListPoly.type]
```

Comment: can you add the error ?

Comment: I have updated question with the compilation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that shapeless defines a `runtimeList` method on `HList` which efficiently computes a `List[Any]` from an `HList`, and also a `toList` method which converts an `HList` to a more precisely typed `List`. Nevertheless, it's interesting to see how this operation can be performed using `fold`.

There are a couple of wrinkles here. The first thing to consider is what the type of the `List` you are accumulating here should be. Most likely you would want the element type of the resulting list to be the least upper bound (LUB) of the types of the elements of the `HList` you're folding over. To get a result of that type we need to compute LUBs as we go.

We also need to accommodate `Nil` as the initial value. `Nil` is a value of type `List[Nothing]` and this is problematic in cases where we need to resolve an implicit indexed by `List[T]`. The type variable `T` would have to be instantiated at `Nothing` to match the type of `Nil`, but unfortunately Scala's type inferencer treats the type `Nothing` as the value of a type variable as meaning "unsolved" ... the result of this is that implicit resolution would fail spuriously. To work around this problem we have to provide an explicit case of `foldListPoly` for `Nil.type`.

Putting this together we end up with,

```
object wrapInList extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[T] = at[T]{v => List(v)}
}

object foldListPoly extends Poly2 {
  implicit  def foldToListNil[U](implicit st: wrapInList.Case.Aux[U, List[U]]) =
    at[Nil.type, U]{ (acc, u) => wrapInList(u) }

  implicit  def foldToList[T, U, L, LL](
    implicit st: wrapInList.Case.Aux[U, List[U]],
    lub: Lub[T, U, L],
    llub: Lub[List[T], List[U], LL],
    ev: LL =:= List[L]
  ) = at[List[T], U]{ (acc, u) => llub.left(acc) ::: llub.right(wrapInList(u)) }
}

scala> ("aoeu" :: 42 :: HNil).foldLeft(Nil)(foldListPoly)
res0: List[Any] = List(aoeu, 42)

scala> (13 :: 23 :: HNil).foldLeft(Nil)(foldListPoly)
res1: List[Int] = List(13, 23)

scala> (23 :: true :: HNil).foldLeft(Nil)(foldListPoly)
res2: List[AnyVal] = List(23, true)
```

Notice that in each case the element type of the resulting list is the LUB of the element types of the `HList`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you generate a `List[String]` for "aoeu" in `wrapInList` which isn't compatible with the next element of `hList` (42, which is an `Int`). If you can live with `List[Any]` (as opposed to the least upper bound), you can do it like this:

```scala
object wrapInList extends Poly1 {
  implicit def intCase = at[Int]{v => List[Any](v)}
  implicit def stringCase = at[String]{v => List[Any](v)}
}

object foldListPoly extends Poly2 {
  implicit  def foldToList[T](implicit st: wrapInList.Case.Aux[T, List[Any]]) =
    at[List[Any], T]{ (acc, t) => acc ::: wrapInList(t) }
}
```

Additionally, you have to explicitly type `Nil` as `List[Any]`:

```scala
val foldedHList2 = hList.foldLeft(Nil:List[Any])(foldListPoly)
```

Comment: i got the idea of incompatible types, but unfortunately this code does not compile and gives the same error when trying to fold over the `hList`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the method call which includes the `List[Any]` type.